# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. still even after assgining a key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just I have been fiddling with ReactJs and ASP.net core and I am wondering why it throws an error that each component should have a key and when I have modified my code to assign a key it keeps displaying the same messagem how could I solve it?

react.development.js:401 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `CommentBox`. See https:// fb . me/react-warning-keys for more information.
in label (created by CommentBox)
in CommentBox

```js
class CommentBox extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const span = React.createElement('span', { className: "span" }, 'First Component React');
        const label = React.createElement('label', { className: "label" }, span);
        const brTag = React.createElement('br')
        const textBox = React.createElement('input', { className: "input", placeholder: "Hola" });
        const upperDiv = React.createElement('div', { key:"upperDivinput", className: "div" }, [label, brTag, textBox]);

        let comments = [];
        let baseUrl = 'https://localhost:44379';
        let endPointComments = '/Posts/GetComments';
        baseUrl = baseUrl + endPointComments;
        fetch(baseUrl)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
                comments = result;
                console.log(result);
            });
        let commentsParagraph = [];
         for (let i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
            console.log(comments[i].author);
            const paragItemTitle = React.createElement('p', { key:'author_${i}' ,className: "p" }, comments[i].author);
            const paragraphItemText = React.createElement('p', { key: 'comment_${i}', className: "p" }, comments[i].text);
            commentsParagraph.push(paragItemTitle);
            commentsParagraph.push(paragraphItemText);
        }
        const lowerDiv = React.createElement('div', { key:"lowerDivComments", className: 'div' }, commentsParagraph);
        const wrapperOuter = React.createElement('div', { key:"wapperDivComments", className:"div" }, [upperDiv, lowerDiv])
        return wrapperOuter;
            
        
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CommentBox />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I don't often use string literal syntax, but `"comment_${i}"` doesn't appear to be doing what you're expecting. I think it should be `\`comment_${i}\`` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))

Comment: Once that is addressed, you can probably remove all the other keys (besides the author one). You only need to provide a key to arrays of elements.

Comment: As @BrianThompson suggest you are not using sting literals correctly. I just wanted to add that you shouldn't be using the index as a key anyway as it is not *stable* on re-renders. Please see [this blog](https://blog.alexdevero.com/react-best-practices-pt2/#7-don8217t-use-indexes-as-a-key-prop) for more information on this.

Comment: @Mushroomator  i have changed to single quotes and still throws the same error but i notice that then(? is it a promise? or a callback? is executing at last... so I think the paragraph arent rendering due to having no data being set on the promise... how could i load data up on startup  of the document load? i found that componentWillMount is deprecated?

Comment: First of all, don't use single quotes `'`. You need to use backticks `\``. And yes `fetch()` and `response.json()` return promises which you need to `await`. Otherwise it won't render what you expect it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use [functional components instead of class components](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-between-functional-components-and-class-components-in-react/). `componentWillMount()` can then be replaced by the [`useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook.
And you should consider using [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) as this is way easier to read then your lengthy `createElement()` calls. Probably best for you to start with the [official React guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html).

As I've mentioned in my comment use ` (=backticks) for string literals. And try to avoid using an index as a key as an index is not stable.

Here a small example of a similar component as the one you want to build that uses string literals, a good key, a functional component and an API request to request some data. Click [this link](https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/comments) to see the dummy data that is returned by the API.

```js
function CommentBox() {
  const [comments, setComments] =  React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const url = "https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/comments";
    const response = fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json().then(json => setComments(json)));
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {comments.map((comment) => (
        <li>
          <span>{`Comment No. ${comment.id} from ${comment.name}`}</span>
          <blockquote>{comment.body}</blockquote>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<CommentBox />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Unfortunately I cannot use async/ await when using React on StackOverflow as I have to tick `Babel/ ES2015` within my snippet. Usually I would use an `async` function in `useEffect()` and use `await` instead of chaining `then()`.

The `useEffect()` hook would then look like this. Both versions result in the same output though.

```js
React.useEffect(async () => {
    const url = "https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/comments";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await resp.json();
    setComments(data);
  }, []);
```

> Please note: you would still need to implement some error handling here.

Comment: Please consider marking this as an [*accepted answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A&text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.) if this worked for you :)

Comment: Yeah it is fine but exactly using this html embedded syntax is a bit more confusing than using functional syntax, I wonder if this map iterated n times and creates all these Li which it wraps? what if I didnt have any comment? how would i fill it out? would you do some conditional?

Comment: Yes, `map()` returns an array of list items. `( )` wraps everything that is returned. You will see this a lot in React. For all your others question I would refer to to [reactpatterns.com](https://reactpatterns.com/) where you will find answer for such common problems and how you could solve them. You could still have `if`/ `else` etc. but quite often you'll find the ternary operator `?` used. This kind of stuff is also covered on the abovementioned website.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is kind of hidden with this kind of code: `[label, brTag, textBox]` and `[upperDiv, lowerDiv]`.

Any time you have an array of elements, every element in that array must have a key. In this case, your label, brTag, and textBox need a key.

Also, you never want to do things like API requests inside your render function. Please use the lifecycle hooks like `componentDidMount` for loading data, and calling `setState` to trigger a new render. DO NOT call `setState` inside your render method.

Also, do yourself and everybody else a favor and use JSX. It's compiled a build time (not run time), so it doesn't cost you any performance and is much easier to read (note: this advice is coming from someone who initially resisted JSX). In such case, you could use react fragments and avoid having to define unnecessary keys:

```js
<>
  <label>...</label>
  <br />
  <input ... />
</>
```